# Dismiss iOS 13 keyboard tutorial when running on a fresh simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios13, xcode11, xcuitest

I am using Xcode 11 & iOS 13 as part of a workflow for a UITest, but when I engage with the keyboard for the first time, the following appears and disrupts the test by blocking the keyboard:

Calling code in UI test:

```
app.textFields.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
```

What the simulator shows:
[image]

Since this obstructs the keys, my test will then fail. However, the next time I run the test on the same simulator, it will work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this that works for both when it encounters the above, as well as on follow up runs where it is not present.

```
let continueButton = app.buttons["Continue"]
if continueButton.exists {
    continueButton.tap()
}
```

The first line attempts to locate a button with the title of **"Continue"**, and then proceeds to verify the existence of this button on the second line. If it does exist, it will then `tap()` it which dismisses the prompt.

Comment: Nice but it doesn't compile since continue is a reserved keyword. Plus there are some other improvements to be made. I am making a new answer to share my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I had edited my original code and just dropped the phrase that made it work. I have since updated to resolve my error.

Answer (score 3):

CodeBender's answer is nice and leads down the right path, but doesn't compile since `continue` is a reserved keyword in Swift. Plus it would be nice to wait a small amount of time for the keyboard to show up.

```swift
    // Sometimes the Apple Keyboard shows some sort of "Swipe" tutorial. Dismiss it!
    private func begoneSwipeTutorial(app: XCUIApplication) {
        let continueButton = app.buttons["Continue"]
        if continueButton.waitForExistence(timeout: 2.0) {
            continueButton.tap()
        }
    }

    // Then use like this
    func inputTextWhatever(app: XCUIApplication, element: XCUIElement) {
        element.tap()
        begoneSwipeTutorial(app: app)
        // Do whatever you need to do
    }
```

Comment: This also works fine. One suggestion could be to make your `inputTextWhatever` function an extension off of `XCUIApplication` just to minimize the parameters it needs. You could then add the `begone` function to the extension as well, so you can easily reuse this throughout your tests.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid possible conflicts when there might be several buttons with `Continue` label I've used this approach:

```
func dismissKeyboardTutorialIfNeeded() {
    let predicate = NSPredicate { (evaluatedObject, _) in
        return (evaluatedObject as? XCUIElementAttributes)?.identifier == "UIContinuousPathIntroductionView"
    }
    let keyboardTutorialView = app.windows.otherElements.element(matching: predicate)
    if keyboardTutorialView.exists {
        keyboardTutorialView.buttons["Continue"].tap()
    }
}
```

When I was testing on iOS 13-15 it all worked well without adding extra wait for tuturial view existence, but it might be needed for older devices.